# Path::join does not do what is expected

Tags: rust

I have this Rust code:

```
use std::env;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn main() {
    let user_home_dir: PathBuf = env::home_dir().expect("Could not find home directory.");
    let images_dir = Path::new(&user_home_dir).join("\\AppData\\Local\\Packages");

    println!("\nUser dir: {:?}", user_home_dir);
    println!("Image folder: {:?}", images_dir);
}
```

This code prints:

```
User dir: "C:\\Users\\username"
Image folder: "C:\\AppData\\Local\\Packages"
```

My expectation is that it should print:

```
User dir: "C:\\Users\\username"
Image folder: "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Packages"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Drop the leading "\\" in `join("\\AppData\\Local\\Packages");`. It's being interpreted as the drive root directory.

Comment: @PeterHall, thanks, your comment makes it easy to understand the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Path::join`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.join) uses the same semantics as [`PathBuf::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.push). Those docs say...

> Pushing an absolute path replaces the existing path:
>
> ```
> use std::path::PathBuf;
>
> let mut path = PathBuf::from("/tmp");
> path.push("/etc");
> assert_eq!(path, PathBuf::from("/etc"));
> ```

`\\AppData\\Local\\Packages` is absolute. You have to make it relative first.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not use OS specific code like `join("\\AppData\\Local\\Packages")`.
Please use `join("AppData").join("Local").join("Packages")` as it uses the platforms path delimiter. It also solves your question because each path element is not absolute.